# JavaFX ComboBox within ComboBox

Tags: javafx, combobox, dropdown

When I try to put a combo box inside another combo box, the inner combo box can be selected fine however I cannot use the inner combo box when it is selected. Is there a way to make the inner combo box functional?

Example code:

```
ComboBox outerBox = new ComboBox();
ComboBox innerBox = new ComboBox();

innerBox.getItems().addAll("item1", "item2", "item3");
outerBox.getItems().add(innerBox);
```

As I said the inner box can be selected but it cannot be used.

Comment: I am going to guess that if you want to do something like this, that you need to use the outer `Combobox` `cellFactory`.

Comment: Not really an answer, but have you looked at using Menus? It seems like a MenuButton with Menus inside it might suit your needs better than comboboxes.

Comment: dont .... controls shouldn't be loaded as data, particularly not into a combo https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html

Comment: @MMAdams menus are a good thought but not quite what I need.

Comment: A somewhat hacky workaround I thought of is listening for a click on the outer box then calling show on the inner box (and hide on the outer box) if the click is within the inner box. There's probably a cleaner solution using cell factories as @Sedrick suggested but I couldn't quite get it, if anyone has an idea how to do it with that (or another) approach I'd love to hear it but for now this'll do.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you even want to use that for? No matter what you are doing, this is probably the wrong approach :D